# A nhibernate session problem about transactions

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I will try to explain in pseudo code.

There're two sessions
s1 and s2

int totalEntity = 0;

```
Thread1
{
s1.BeginTransaction ();
loop (infinite)
{
   totalEntity = s1.List<Entity> ().Count ();
}
s1.EndTransaction ();
}


s2.BeginTransaction ();
s2.Insert<Entity> ();
s2.EndTransaction ();
```

When i run the s2, the totalEntity still is zero because the s1.Transaction not commited. How can i get the real totalEntity as 1, in the loop?

Comment: Which database are you using? Which transaction isolation level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call flush, it'll cause the db to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if the transaction is inside the loop.